# Software, countable or uncountable?

Tags: articles, nouns

I have come across an article titled " [Scientists have invented a software that allows you to see several minutes into the future](https://www.google.com.tw/amp/s/www.sciencealert.com/neural-network-software-predicting-human-actions-future-minutes/amp)".

Software is an uncountable noun. Don't we usually say" a piece of software" instead of  "a software"?

Comment: Yes, we do usually say *a piece of software*. That would be better English. It'd be wonderful if you could provide the link to the article you're reading so that we all could see who wrote it.

Comment: Related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/63241/9161

Comment: Don't look to clickbait sites like Science Alert and its ilk for examples of how to use English. And in about 99% of cases, I would say don't look to them for science, either. There is so much oversimplified, misinterpreted, and hyped up writing there that I would think robots were writing it.

Comment: Here is the link. https://www.google.com.tw/amp/s/www.sciencealert.com/neural-network-software-predicting-human-actions-future-minutes/amp

Comment: Thank you Choster. I am beginning to think so as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, good catch. There's a mistake in the article you read. It is likely that the person who wrote the article is not a native speaker of English.

Another way to write it would be

> Scientists have invented software that allows you to see several minutes into the future.