# What do you call a piece of software inside another software that could be considered a software on its own?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a piece of software inside another software that could be considered a software on its own? I am looking for a language and technology independent word for it. Is there a word for it, the only think I can think of is "part of a software that's also software on its own", but that's too long, I am looking for a single word. I also am trying to find a word extremely general that could be used in almost any context.

Comment: Related Question:  [Software, countable or uncountable?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169579)

Comment: "Software" is a mass noun.  "A software" is incorrect, but "a piece of software" is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Component", "[tool](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/T/tool.html)", and "program" are all words for pieces of software that can either stand alone, or be part of a larger software [application](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/A/app.html).

An exception:  In Visual Basic, "components" and "widgets" are only available as part of dynamic linked libraries.  In programming environments similar to Visual Basic, "components" are not stand-alone programs that can be called from the command line.